# How can I create a hash table (I think this is called a Dictionary in VBA) of dynamic arrays that store ranges in VBA for Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, data-structures

The problem: I have a large table of sales records, and one of the columns is the state in which the sale took place. I need to copy every sale from a given state to a separate workbook for that state. I could open a state's workbook and then scan the table and copy the data each time I find a sale from that state in the table, and continue this process, but it is a bit slow since it is scanning the entire table for each state. I would prefer to scan the table once and push all of the sales (each being represented by a section of  a row in Excel) on to an array that can be referred to by the states name; these array should by dynamic because I don't know how many sales each state has. So, essentially, I want a hash table with the name of the state being keys and dynamic arrays that store ranges being the values. Is this possible? If not is there a better approach?

Comment: You could try to use ADO, and SQL on the spreadsheets will speed things up.

Comment: I am not familiar with ADO at the moment, but would it essentially let me write SQL statements to get information strait from an Excel table? I thought ADO was only for getting data from a database into Excel, am I mistaken?

Comment: No, you are mistaken, ADO, is a connection to a variety of data types, databases being the most used I'd imagine, but your Excel workbook will be the equivalent of the DB, and each tab, equivalent of a table.  Google Query Excel using ADO.   You can write SQL and query using where x="Sale" for example.

Comment: That's awesome, I will investigate some more. Thank you.

Comment: I did as a scoping, opening workbooks and taking the data, took close to 20mins, using SQL in the final version, it now takes <10seconds.

Comment: And you were able to write all of the code and execute it from the worksheet that contained your data? Because, this is a growing project, so workbooks are continuously being added, which isn't a problem in my current set up it is just slow. I need all the code to be located in one workbook.

Comment: Hi, no, I wrote to query and collate 18 workbooks, you cant query the one you're in, so you need to save a temp copy, I thought you were querying workbook after workbook?

Comment: No I have one workbook that has the sales data (in one worksheet), and after the user adds data to the worksheet, I want that data to be added to other workbooks that use that very same data. I am trying to make it so that the user doesn't have to enter the same data multiple times.

Comment: If you have Excel 2016 then you could achieve this with the built-in [Get & Transform tools](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Getting-Started-with-Get-Transform-in-Excel-2016-a8310388-2a12-438c-9d29-c6d29cb8df6a) on the Data tab of the ribbon. If you have Excel 2010 or 2013 you could [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379) the PowerQuery add-in which works in the same way - details [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6E92E2F4-2079-4E1F-BAD5-89F6269CD605)

Comment: @barrow Thank you for this tip, I am looking into it right now, it appears to solve my problem. It doesn't seem as if this is going to be a quick fix in my case (because it is a new technology to learn), but it looks like a better approach than using VBA to automate the copying of data across multiple workbooks.